# Debugging android apps on the kindle fire

Tags: android, debugging, kindle-fire

Is debugging Android applications remotely from eclipse supported for Kindle Fire platform?

Comment: No exp developing android app.. but did a good search for your question and go this.. http://androidforums.com/application-development/429988-kindle-fire-development.html :)

Comment: I did another search and found this: http://www.technipages.com/kindle-fire-enable-usb-debugging.html in order to allow for remote debugging over USB (using DDMS). I'm not sure what adding the vendor ID to the configuration file actually does - it looks like it might inform adb about an additional kind of USB vendor (Amazon?) that it should consider as an Android device.

Comment: See a specific question/answer for Ubuntu:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257201/how-can-usb-debugging-for-kindle-fire-can-be-enabled-on-a-linux-ubuntu-machine

Answer (score 57, accepted):

According to [Amazon's FAQ on Kindle Fire](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire), Kindle Fire has USB debugging enabled by default. To connect Kindle Fire to your Android Debug Bridge (ADB) follow the instructions in [this PDF](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf).If you are working with Windows 7 you will need to download and use [this driver](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/kindle-fire-windows-7-driver.zip). They are also providing USB drivers for download for Windows 7 PC. Moreover, we can also emulate Kindle Fire specs on Android emulator by using the following parameters.

- Width: 600px
- Height: 1024px
- Abstracted LCD Density: 169
- Target: Android 2.3.4 - API Level 10
- RAM: 512 MB

They don't offer separate developer devices. You can use the Kindle Fire devices which you can buy online.

After installing the device driver, I had to modify your adb_usb.ini

1. Open the C:\Users\< your-login >\.android\adb_usb.ini file for editing
2. Add 0x1949
3. Save the file

[image: I could set up Amazon Kindle Fire for debugging. Pic:]

Comment: Had trouble figuring out how to restart adb - the path to the file is not found in terminal - can anyone help?

Comment: set <Android-SDK>/tools and <Android-SDK>/platform-tools in PATH system environment variable. 

Alternatively you can do it from eclipse. Go to DDMS -> go to devices view, there reset adb option will be there in the more options.

Comment: I just made a batch file to reset the adb for me since it is needed often.

Comment: I would be nevious about download this generic driver from 2012... use the one on the SDK manager under extras.. and add the VID and PID to your inf.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to easily install an unsigned APK of your app for testing: http://androidforums.com/amazon-kindle-fire/448193-install-any-app-kindle-fire.html

Answer (score 2):

I found that this post is helpful enable usb debugging. Although it is not as simple as 1,2 3. There are a number of steps involved to enable it. But it can be done. http://www.freerepairguide.com/kindle-fire-enable-usb-debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

One drawback to debugging on Fire that you do not find on other devices - when your computer is connected to the Fire device it has blocked the I/O Socket. If your app downloads any files while it is running you will receive an alert that the file could not be downloaded but the debug error in the log will actually show that there was an I/O error. Unplugging the USB cable and attempting to download again will work, but when you plug back in you're back to square one with it wanting to install your app all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your app target AIR version MUST be no greater than version installed on KF.
Otherwise you have to update AIR on KF. (I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423923/debugging-adobe-air-apps-on-kindle-fire) how to do it)