# How can usb debugging for Kindle Fire can be enabled on a Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: android, linux, adb

I am trying to do some Android development on a Kindle Fire, however I am having trouble making my Ubuntu 11.04 recognize the device for using it with the ADB. I've added a line like this `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1949", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"` in my etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file, restarted the computer and plugged in the Fire but still `adb devices` did not show it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that it works if you edit ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and add 2 lines containing 0x1949 and 0x006 and restart the adb server using

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Also, the 51-android.rules file contains the Lab126 vendor id.

You may also need to edit the inf file.  See the instructions here:
http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf

Comment: Doing this alone didn't work for me on Win7x64. I had to use the full instructions in David's answer.

Comment: Well, this question was specifically for Ubuntu, so it doesn't solve the problem for other OS's. Probably works for other Linux distros, but I only tested this on Ubuntu.

Comment: This does work, if you also follow the steps here relating to the inf file: http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf  The inf file steps are the same thing David's site lists.

Comment: Should be "0x0006" (three zeros)

Comment: Make sure not to add a new line character after 0x0006, it could mess up adb.

Comment: this , together with the question , has worked well for me . thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a single line to: ~/.android/adb_usb.ini. The content of the line: 0x1949
2. Restart server

   $ adb kill-server

   $ **sudo** adb start-server

Worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1):

There will be a number of steps you have to take. Basically you need to edit an ini file. Different steps is needed for MAC and PC.
[Kindle Fire: Enable USB Debugging](http://www.freerepairguide.com/kindle-tips.html)

Comment: aaand the link is wrong now. This is why cut'n'paste or at least a summary is usually preferred.