# ADB cannot detect my Kindle Fire on Windows 7, but Device Manager can

Tags: android, windows-7, adb, kindle-fire

So I've thrown the book at this problem and think I've isolated the cause.

I've downloaded and installed JDK 32 and 64 bit.
I've installed the Android SDK as needed.
I've modified android_winusb.inf inside of the google-usb-driver to include the Kindle Fire device IDs.
I tried downloading the kindle fire windows 7 driver from amazon (as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189488/debugging-android-apps-on-the-kindle-fire)), and using that.

I tried modifying that driver to include the fire device ID in the x86 section.

I've killed and restarted adb diligently, and restarted my comp several times to see if that would magically fix it. nothing.

The only thing I'm unsure about is the modification of adb_usb.ini. Unfortunately, my .android folder doesn't exist in my %USERPROFILE%, but instead exists in another location on my computer. That folder doesn't have adb_usb.ini either. So I copied the contents of .android to my %USERPROFILE%, and created adb_usb.ini in each, and added 0x1949 to that empty file.

This did not work. adb devices still turns up zilch.

I think adb is having trouble finding my adb_usb.ini, but really, I have no idea. And if that is the case, I don't know how to fix that. Help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815769/1778421

Answer (score 6):

Just adding 0x1949 to the adb_usb.ini was enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have added the right product/vendor id in adb_usb.ini file.

I had the same exact problem only after adding 0x1949 I could see the device listed. 
Either amazon is changing the id's or people are giving wrong id's in random forums. The first one is definitely not required.

After adding the product id's my adb_usb.ini looks like this and I don't think your .android location matters

```
0x0e79 
0x006 
0x1949
```

Answer (score 3):

This was driving me crazy also. Did recommendations from other links and posts and did not work. After running adb command without options, I saw an option for usb. I executed the following:

```
adb kill-server
adb usb
```

you should see some output after this, I didn't save the results

```
adb devices
```

Now showed my device

Answer (score 1):

Type out your `adb_usb.ini`

```
cd /users/username
type adb_usb.ini
```

Make sure it shows `0x1949...` mine had a special character instead of the x.  Edit the file and change it manually to an x.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, I copied and pasted the 0x1949 directly from a rooting article and the 'x' was a slightly different character than the standard x.  When I deleted and replaced 'x' manually it showed right up.

Answer (score 1):

your device driver is not working go to the following link and update

http://www.jayceooi.com/2011/12/13/how-to-install-kindle-fire-adb-usb-driver/

Answer (score 1):

Also double check that Windows isn't being sneaky and actually saving your adb_usb.ini as adb_usb.ini.txt when you create the file from scratch!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Windows was using the default driver. I uninstalled the windows driver.

Installed the driver at `\android-sdk\extras\amazon\kindle_fire_usb_driver`. Ran the following:

```
adb kill-server
adb usb
```

You should see some output after this, I didn't save the results:

```
adb devices
```

Device finally showed up.  Kindle then showed up in device manager.  Was not showing up there before.

Answer (score 1):

In the %android_sdk%\extras\amazon\kindle_fire_usb_driver folder you can find KindleDrivers.exe file. Just run it and Kindle drivers for Windows (Win7 in my case) will be installed.

Comment: Just in case, if you can't find that file in that path like me, you can download it from:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing
Direct link:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/kindle_fire_usb_driver.zip

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you've done all the right things. For me the adb_usb.ini file did the trick and it's in c:/users/dirk/.android/adb_usb.ini. Oddly, I also added the product id of 0x006 on another line, thought I don't think that matters (the 0x1949 is the vendor id).

Make sure the adb_usb.ini is in the same folder as your avd folder. You can try creating a new AVD and look around to see under which user the new one was created.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the exact same problem as you and I also had a problem with it looking for java.exe in my c drive instead of my d. I fixed this issue the same way I fixed that. Use the "mklink" command line tool to create a symbolic link in the C drive to your .android folder on your other drive. My exact command was:

`mklink /D .android D:\.android`

I was in my `C:\Users\<User Name>\` folder

After that I ran adb kill-server and adb devices again and it showed up!

Hope that helps.

Comment: this looks really promising, Michael thanks! Will check if it works later today and accept if so :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this worked for me

```
0x1949
0x006
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue for the longest time - Michael's answer lead me to the answer that fixed this for me.

If you don't currently have a `C:\Users\[Username]\.android` folder, add one manually. Copy `adb_usb.ini` into this folder. Windows may give you some trouble if you try to create this folder in Windows Explorer (beginning the folder with a period, probably). I had to open `cmd` and type `move android .android` to accomplish this.

After doing this, adb devices immediately showed the device.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is simple: for some reason when you install the drivers, the version of adv_usb.ini in the user/.android does not contain the vendor ID

I've check and the file was plain.

All that I had to do was to copy the ini file from the driver folder into username/.android and do a adb kill-server, followed by adb usb and the device was recognized.

Answer (score 0):

In general, running "android update adb" from the /Tools folder should be enough to update the correct adb_usb.ini file.  The location of this file is relevant as adb will only look for one of them.  I had a CRC error in sdkuilib.jar, and it would not copy.  This caused "android update adb" to fail, so my adb_usb.ini file did not get updated.

Also, when I went to update by hand, I was logged on as joe user, but I elevated to admin user to perform the update.  I modified the joe user copy of adb_usb.ini (c:\users\JoeUser.android\adb_usb.ini), but the adb program looked instead at the admin copy of adb_usb.ini (c:\users\Admin.android\adb_usb.ini).  So, adb did not see the 0x1949 that I added by hand.

Once I replaced my copy of sdkuilib.jar (by redownloading, installing in a separated folder, and copying over the bad file), I was able to run "android update adb" and 0x01949 showed up in my admin adb_usb.ini. [To find this, I changed echo off to echo on at the top of both the android.bat and find_java.bat files.]

After that, I did an adb kill-server and adb usb.  But I still got the "error: device not found" message.  Only then did I notice that my Kindle Fire had timed out.  I turned it back on, unlocked it, and at that point, the kill-server "adb usb" sequence produced "restarting in USB mode".

Once that output was produced, the adb devices showed my Kindle Fire.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers' reference:

Don't forget to turn on USB debugging on the device. (At least in my case, on OUYA, this is disabled by default.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows and you have the Android SDK installed (if `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable is set) then `adb` will use `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\.android\adb_usb.ini` instead of `%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini`

Also [this post](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html) has a command to populate your `adb_usb.ini` with Vendor IDs of all currently connected `adb` devices.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to install Kindle Fire drivers.

If you can't find it in your local disk, you can download from official Amazon page:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing

Direct link:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/kindle_fire_usb_driver.zip