# Android Studio No devices connected

Tags: android-studio, adb

Running windows 7 and I have just downloaded the latest android studio version and started a project and now I'd like to test the application on my device but Android Studio says on the bottom left "No devices connected". I've tried a couple of things such as:

1. updating my Samsung S6 edge drivers through device manager, which were updated now.
2. have debugging mode turned on and USB debugging mode on.
3. ran 'adb devices' command to list devices but none show up.
4. downloaded new universal adb drivers.
5. toggled between MTP and PTP modes.
6. restarted computer/phone/android studio/ adb tens of times.
7. deleted phones drivers from device manager and installed again.
8. re-installed android studio.
9. probably some other small things too that I can't remember right now.

I'm at a loss as of right now, if someone can help me out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried editing adb_usb.ini with your device's usb info? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347561/adb-cannot-detect-my-kindle-fire-on-windows-7-but-device-manager-can

Comment: @adelphus I'll try that now

Comment: @adelphus just tried adding adb_usb.ini file with my vendor (samsung) to the file saved it in C:\Users\{user}\.android, killed adb server and restarted but still no luck in listing devices

Comment: So once I added the adb_usb.ini file I toggled between MTP and PTP and once I brought it back to MTP mode the device is responding now! Thanks for the suggestion to add the ini file! @adelphus

Comment: Samsung has always been on the `adb`'s hardcoded whitelist - so Samsung devices (with the original stock firmware) never needed the `adb_usb.ini` changes to work. It must be something else you did.