# Debugging Adobe AIR apps on Kindle Fire

Tags: air, kindle-fire

Possible?

I think to do this I need to upgrade the AIR runtime on the Fire to 3, but the version in the app store won't install. I can't create an AIR apk that is both captive runtime and debug that I know of, so the debug version of the app has to run on the AIR runtime installed. Since the Fire comes with 2.7, 3.x apps won't run in debug mode.

Has anyone managed to get AIR 3 running on a Fire without using captive runtime?

Answer (score 1):

To update AIR on your KF you have to get root privileges. Also keep in mind that android build on KF doesn't have any copy command (it cut off). So the best way I found is to flash your KF with modified (pre-rooted) stock version and then install new air.

1. Get pre-rooted stock version (I took it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1569298)). IMPORTANT: it installs via TWRP, google how to install TWRP on KF.
2. Put downloaded .zip and air_runtime.apk (latest AIR version) in the root of KF.
3. Reboot in Recovery mode (TWRP should load)
4. Flash this version.
5. On your PC open cmd and run "adb shell" (make sure you see your device in list when run "adb devices" otherwise check drivers).
6. Run "su" (if you downloaded secure version).
7. In shell go to sdcard ("ls" to get list of files/folders and "cd folder_name" to get into) and run "install air_runtime.apk /system/app/air_runtime.apk" (I think you can just run "install /sdcard/folder_with_air/air_runtime.apk /system/app/air_runtime.apk").
   (7a. If it tells you that can't install because of file already exist, run the following two commands: "mount -o remount rw /system" (mount 'system' with read/write rights) and "mv /system/app/air_runtime.apk /system/app/air_runtime.bak" (rename air_runtime.apk into air_runtime.bak). Then repeat step 7.)
8. In KF just run (install) air_runtime.apk (use any file explorer, e.g. download ES File Explorer from Amazon).
9. Check AIR version in Applications.

That's all. Looks a bit complex, but in real it takes about 4-5 mins for me to update AIR (BUT I have TWRP already installed).

Hope it helps.

UPD. After your Kindle updates itself (version 6.3.1 currently the latest) you'll lose you SU privileges. AIR also will be rolled back to 2.7. You can prevent KF auto-updates (search on xda how to do it) or flash actual pre-rooted version (it gives you several months without problems).

Comment: I'm not familiar with what "stock version" is. How different is that build from what is on the Kindle in the first place? My concern is that I don't want to change the OS so much that I end up with a standard Android system that just happens to be running on a Fire, instead of a Kindle OS with all of the peculiarities specific to Amazon's version.

Comment: Scott, this is exact the same version as is on Kindle Fire (KF UI 6.2.2., android 2.3.4). The only change is that xda version has superuser access to file system, services, etc.

Comment: One more point, Scott. After your Kindle updates itself (version 6.3.1 currently the latest) you'll lose you SU privileges. AIR also will be rolled back to 2.7. You can either prevent auto-updates (look in xda how to do it) or find latest rooted stock version. I updated my answer with this point and new link (6.3 rooted stock - the latest I found).